# get other user feed using facebook php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am trying to get other users feed in PHP using Facebook Graph API PHP sdk, but with no success.

i got my feed properly using

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

But i trying to get other user feed like

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/534551234549753/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

is return me this blank response

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

is there any way to get other user's feed ?

Answer (score 2):

You can only read the feed of a user if he authorized your App. And you can only get his feed with his very own User Access Token.

Since you will not get `read_stream` approved at all, i suggest using the new `user_posts` permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

But again: You can ONLY get the feed of the authorized user, not from anyone else. That would be a major privacy issue.

Answer (score 0):

A look in the Facebook docs might have saved you the time for writing your question:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed/#readperms

You can read other user's feeds if you have an app which requests the appropriate permissions during OAuth login:

> **Permissions**
>
> Any valid access token is required to view public links.
>   If the app has been granted the `read_stream` or `user_posts` permission the app can read:
>
> - The user's posts on their own Timeline.
> - The posts others have made on the user's Timeline.
> - The posts others have tagged the user in.